# Resolve Identity column primary key conflict while sync b/w two sql server 2005 db

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, sql-server-express, microsoft-sync-framework

I have two sql server 2005 database - `ParentDB` and `ChildDB`, and i want to synchronize them using sync framework 2.1
`ParentDB` is on server and `ChildDB` is on client m/c. There are many tables in `ParentDB` but few tables on `ChildDB`, Lets say, a `Customer` table is common between both db with `Id (column)` as primary key set to auto increment, and i want to synchronize this table, i am using the approach given in the following msdn [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700.aspx). This appraoch worked unless i do only download from server or upload to server.

Lets take a scenario :
1. There is a row with Id=52 on server table
2. Both db's are synchronized
3. Now a row is inserted on `ParentDB`in `Customer` table with Id=53
4. At same-time another row is inserted on `ChildDB` in `Customer` table with Id=53 (since both tables has auto increment)
Now when i synchronize both tables either of the two row gets overridden, depending on the direction of synchronization.
What i want is that `Id` is adjusted, and both rows are retained,

What should i do to resolve such conflict, if possible please provide pseudo code.
P.S. : I expect when we consider foreign key constraint then scenario will get more complicated.
Thnx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using Identity columns as a PK in a synchronization environment (or even not using Sync Framework) is not recommended (see [Selecting an Appropriate Primary Key for a Distributed Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726011.aspx) for the same reason that you have already found out.

if you can change the schema, i suggest you use a different PK (Guid, or Int + ClientId)